# Error "ReplicatedStorage.Moonlite:669: attempt to index nil with 'IsPlaying'"

Tags: roblox

Error In [Moonlite](https://github.com/MaximumADHD/Moonlite) `ReplicatedStorage.Moonlite:669: attempt to index nil with 'IsPlaying'`

My Script:

```
print("Importing...")
Moonlite = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.Moonlite)
print("Createing Player...")
Track = Moonlite.CreatePlayer(game.ReplicatedStorage.Animation)
print("Play Animation...")
Track.Looped = true
Track.Play()
```

Tried Edit The Moonlite, but i got new error. Now Script Moonlite is original